# Will using style in layout help to reduce apk size?

Tags: android, android-layout, apk

I just had a thought that, Is applying style to hundreds/thousands of my attributes defined in xml layout files will help me to reduce my apk size as it will reduce the no of lines in code?

I know applying styles is very good method to reduce in writing the same code again and again. But will it also help in reducing the apk size?

Even in bytes or kbs is good.